# Same code on one server runs super slow on one site but fast on another

Tags: performance, iis-7

I'm trying to troubleshoot why <strike>our ASP</strike> all pages  pages are running agonizingly slow.  As a test I created a simple hello world ASP page.  On the same server, one site will pull it up fast as expected, but on another site it will 30+ seconds!

**UPDATE: I actually realized that it's not just asp, it's all pages, so its some kind of core issue.  A 404 page will take 15 seconds to display even.  However their are sites on the same server that pop right up without delay.

The only difference I know of is that the site that generates at the acceptable speed is running Coldfusion code, but I can't imagine a reason why that would effect it at all.

I'm not really sure where to go and what to check from here.

FYI running IIS7 on Server 2008R2

Comment: Does it take 30+ seconds every time or only the first time? ASP or ASP .NET? It could be an initial overhead of compilation, if the application pool is being shared across other sites.

Comment: I just edited the original post.  It's not just ASP, apparently it's all types of pages. It's on every page load, not just the first time.  As I mentioned above it even takes 15 seconds for a 404 page to load.  But again, we have other sites on the same server that load up just fine.

Comment: Couldn't answer my own question for 6 hours, so I have to post here: Ok, found the problem.  The DefaultAppPool was stopped :-/.  Started it and all is well with the cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. The DefaultAppPool was stopped :-/. Started it and all is well with the cosmos